# Remove extra slash

Tags: bash

My script reads the name of folders in current directory:

`for D in */ ; do
 echo $D
 done`

The result is:

folder1/

folder2/

folder3/

But when I want to use $D like this:

```
mv *.zip /home/user/$D/zipfolder
```

it makes two /-s like /home/user/folder1//zipfolder
and it fails

How do I remove the extra /?

Comment: The extra slash shouldn't be a problem, but you could remove it by using `mv *.zip /home/user/${D}zipfolder` instead of your current path. Once the `/` is removed, we need to write `$D` as `${D}` to avoid evaluating `$Dzipfolder` instead of our var.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on bash version **4.2** or higher you can use `${D:0:-1}` as support for negative length was added.

If you are on an earlier version you would need to write `${D:0:${#D}-1}`

But as suggested correctly in a comment below, it might be the case you don't have a slash as a last character, still with that solution above the last character will be removed...

If this is not acceptable, you might want to use `${D%/}` as nothing happens when the last character isn't a **/**

Comment: Or `${D%/}`? The negative indexing requires Bash 4.3 or newer, and it will always remove the last character, no matter what it is. With `%/`, nothing happens if the last character isn't `/`.

Comment: mainly that matches any last character. (bash 4.3: 2014-02-26)

Comment: @BenjaminW. good call! edited the post, I think it was 4.2 where the support was added, maybe I'm wrong, bout to check out

Comment: You're right, I was looking at `array[-idx]` for assignments, which was in 4.3 (https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/061).

Comment: Under which circumstances can `for D in */` lead to some $D, not ending in `/`? Is it reasonable, to prepare for such cases?

Answer (score 1):

```
for D in */ 
do
  echo $D
  ls /home/user/$D/zipfolder
done
```

The example with mv *.zip doesn't make much sense, since once the files are moved, why would you need a for-loop? So I changed the sample to something better reproducible.

Aaron made the suggestions I would have given, but since he didn't answer, and Kristianmitk's answer isn't satisfying, I repeat the comment as an answer.

a) Two slashes don't hurt.

```
  ls a/b
  ls a//b
  ls a/./b
```

all evaluate to the same directory. This is handy in your case, since the slash is a natural terminator for the variable name

```
  ls a/b/c
  ls a/bb/c
  ls a/bb/./c
  D=bb/
  ls a/$D/c 
  ls a/$D./c
```

Even the dot terminates a variable name, so the last line will work, too.

b) If you're irritated by two slashes, you may use curly braces, which is the canonical way, to isolate variable names from surrounding characters:

```
  ls a/${D}c
```

or

```
for D in */ 
do
  echo $D
  ls /home/user/${D}zipfolder
done
```

Comment: @Aaron: Thanks, you're right. I must have done something wrong, while testing it. Tested again, and it worked. Corrected.